# what happens if ieeefloat64 variable is not initialized in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ieee-754

I want to know what happens when we not initialize an ieeefloat64 variable in c++.

```
IEEE_FLOAT64 x;
cout << x;
```

As of now, i m getting output as -9.255963E+061. Is this a random junk value?

Comment: We get undefined behavior (if IEEE_FLOAT64 is not a class with a default constructor which initializes itself).

Comment: What is `IEEE_FLOAT64`?  How is it defined?

Comment: IEEE_FLOAT64 is a datatype defined under IEEE standards, which provides double precision and it is used as hardware floating units.@NathanOliver

Comment: In the context of C++ language it is either a base language type, which it is not, either declared somewhere. What is the declaration of    IEEE_FLOAT64 in C++?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the compiler.
Visual C++ will initialise it to 0 if it is in debug mode, but will leave it uninitializedd if it is release mode.

If its uninitialized its value could be anything, so don't do it.

Comment: I m getting -9.255963E+061. what does this value mean?
Is this a junk value?

Comment: Yes.  That's because you haven't set it, you are getting what ever happened to be in memory before you variable was allocated that memory. `IEEE_FLOAT64 x(0);` will fix the problem.

Comment: But if its a random junk value, then why i m getting same value everytime i run the application?

Comment: It is not random. It is the value of the memory bytes allocated for the variable (if it does not have a constructor.) May happen, that every time you run the application the memory is set to this value.